# is Javascript's 'delete()' being deprecated?

Tags: javascript

thought I had read that `delete()` was being deprecated in some future version of Javascript.

the reason, as I recall, is that if the properties in an ES6 object, once declared, cannot be added or deleted, then performance is much better.

does anyone know the once and future state of `delete`?

Comment: It's not. PS: it's not a function so does not need to have parentheses.

Comment: I don't know about the the function, if there is one, but the `delete` **operator** is not being deprecated

Comment: Sets and Maps have a `Set.delete()`, maybe that's what you're talking about, but it's not being deprecated either ?

Comment: @adeneo it's interpreted as the `delete` operator and the operand, which may be wrapped in optional parentheses. So both `delete a.b;` and `delete(a.b);` behave the same.

Comment: @zerkms - Surrounding the operand with parentheses does not make the operator a function, even if it may look that way, generally when you add empty parentheses at the end, it denotes a function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no much changes with the `delete` operator. As of 2017, it is still fully in effect. Here's the es specs:

- [ES5](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.4.1)
- [ES6](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-delete-operator)
- [ES7](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/#sec-delete-operator-runtime-semantics-evaluation)

In short, `delete` keyword only works for references, and doesn't work to function, vars or function's arguments.

```
function deleteObjectProperty() {
  var x = {a: 'deleteMe'};
  var y = [1,2,3];
  console.log(x.a); // Returns 'deleteMe'
  delete x; // This will return 'false', deletion is not successful
  console.log(x.a); // Still returns 'deleteMe'
  delete x.a; // 'true', deletion is successful
  delete x.b; // 'true', deletion is successful
  console.log(x.a) // 'null'
  delete y[0]; // 'true', array is now [empty, 2, 3]
}

function invalidDeletion(arg1) {
  var x = {a: 'deleteMe'};

  Object.defineProperty(x, "nonConfigurableProperty", {  
      value: 101,
      configurable: false
  });

  /* These dont work */
  delete x; // deleting variable
  delete deleteObjectProperty; // deleting function
  delete arg1; // deleting arguments
  delete x.nonConfigurableProperty; // deleting non-configurable property
}

function invalidDeletionWithStrict() {
  'use strict';
  var x = {a: 'deleteMe'};

  Object.defineProperty(x, "nonConfigurableProperty", {  
      value: 101,
      configurable: false
  });

  /* SyntaxError is thrown here */
  delete x; // deleting variable
  delete deleteObjectProperty; // deleting function
  delete arg1; // deleting arguments

  /* TypeError is thrown here */
  delete x.nonConfigurableProperty; // deleting non-configurable property
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I think that Mozilla JavaScript reference is quite reliable. There is a [specification](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete#Specifications) section that says the *delete* operator was defined in ECMAScript 1st Edition and it is also in the last draft of [ECMAScript 2016 Draft (7th Edition, ECMA-262)](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-delete-operator).